# pandas sort alphabetically for every row based on column content

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| Bonnie | Anna |
| Connor | Ethan |
| Sophia | Daniel |

And I want to sort its content alphabetically so that the final result is:

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| Anna | Bonnie |
| Connor | Ethan |
| Daniel | Sophia |

I want each pair to be ordered alphabetically. As they are in different columns, I don't know how to sort them directly with *sort_values* method. Thanks!

Comment: Did you have an error in the example? In your second case, col2 row2 shouldn't be Daniel and then in col1 row3 Ethan? Otherwise I don't understand what do you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort each row with `DataFrame.apply`

```py
out = (df.apply(lambda row: sorted(row), axis=1, result_type='expand')
       .set_axis(df.columns, axis=1))
```

```
print(out)

     Col1    Col2
0    Anna  Bonnie
1  Connor   Ethan
2  Daniel  Sophia
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data = df.to_numpy()
data.sort(axis=1)
pd.DataFrame(data, columns=df.columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a list for each row, then sort that list:

```
col_names = dta.columns # save the column names
dta = dta.apply(lambda x:list(x), axis=1) # convert each row to a list
dta = dta.apply(lambda x: sorted(x)) # sorting the row lists
dta = dta.to_list() # convert the Series to a list
dta = pd.DataFrame(dta) # recreate the data frame
dta.columns = col_names # replace the name of columns
```

Also you can do the whole thing in one line:

```
dta = pd.DataFrame(dta.apply(lambda x: sorted(list(x)), axis=1).to_list())
dta.columns = col_names
```

result:

|  | Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Anna | Bonnie |
| 1 | Connor | Ethan |
| 2 | Daniel | Sophia |

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
df[['col1', 'col2']] = pd.DataFrame(
    zip(*df[['col1', 'col2']].apply(sorted, axis=1).values)
).T
```